# `std::thread::sleep` inside a busy loop within asynchronous methods

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a rust program where I have a method defined in a thread thread which gets triggered every 24 hours. The main function is defined as follows:-

```
use tokio::task;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<String, String> {
   // spawing `trigger` in a separate thread
   task::spawn(async move {
        utilities::trigger().await
   });

   // other logic 
   Ok("Success".to_string())
}
```

`utilities` is a crate which defines the async method `trigger` as defined below:-

`utilities.rs`

```
pub async trigger() {
 loop {
   // other logic
   // put the thread to sleep for 1 day
   std::thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(86400000));
 }
}
```

The above code logic works for me but I would like to know if there are better ways to achieve this. Furthermore, I read in this [link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html), that the function is blocking, and should not be used in async functions. Are there better ways to rewrite the `trigger` method in Rust.

Answer (score 2):

Tokio has its own, asynchronous version of [`sleep`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html) that won't block the thread but only put the task to sleep, keeping your thread free to handle other tasks.

Also, you could use more sophisticated scheduling crates, like [`cron`](https://docs.rs/cron/latest/cron/):

```
use chron::Schedule;
use chrono::Utc;
use std::str::FromStr;

// schedule task to run each day at midnight
let expr = "00 00 00 * * *";
let s = Schedule::from_str(expr).unwrap();

tokio::task::spawn(async move {
    loop {
        let next_execution = 
            s.upcoming(Utc).next().unwrap_or(Utc::now());

        let sleep_till = (next_execution - Utc::now())
            .to_std()
            .unwrap_or(Duration::ZERO);

         tokio::time::sleep(sleep_till).await;
         
         // your logic here
    }
});
```